# How can I do to profile ruby Unit tests execution?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'd like to know how much took to run the 10 most time consuming tests.. like I can do with rspec, any suggestion?

Comment: Another solution would be to know how much took each test, not just the 10 most time consuming.

Comment: Perhaps [this plugin](http://github.com/timocratic/test_benchmark) can help you.

Comment: Right now i'm trying to port rspec to unit test...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

```
gem install minitest # Install MiniTest
gem install minitest_tu_shim # Install Test::Unit shim
use_minitest yes # Use MiniTest Test::Unit shim instead of stdlib Test::Unit 
ruby your_test.rb -v # Run your test in verbose mode
```

Ruby 1.9 use [`MiniTest`](http://blog.zenspider.com/minitest/) as its default testing framework instead of [`Test::Unit`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit.html). MiniTest is smaller, faster, has more useful features, and is largely backward compatible with Test::Unit. One of those newer features is measuring the time each test takes with the `-v` flag. When you run the e sure you place this flag after the script

If, as in rails, you use [`Rake::TestTask`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html) to run your tests, you'll can either specify it at runtime by running

```
rake test TESTOPTS='-v'
```

or specify it in the task by adding `-v` to the `options` attribute, like so

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.options = '-v'
end
```

Finally, if you're using rails and MiniTest just isn't good enough for you, you might appreciate the [`test_benchmark`](http://github.com/timocratic/test_benchmark) plugin. Usage is easy. Add the following line to your `config/environments/test.rb`

```
config.gem "timocratic-test_benchmark",
  :lib => 'test_benchmark',
  :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

Install it with

```
RAILS_ENV='test' rake gems:install
```

From then on, you'll get a nice sorted list when you run your tests

```
rake test:units
[...]
Test Benchmark Times: Suite Totals:
7.124 test_destroy(FeedTest)
7.219 test_create(FeedTest)
7.646 test_subscribe_to_auto_discovery(FeedTest)
9.339 test_auto_discover_updates_url(FeedTest)
9.543 test_find_or_create_by_auto_discover_url(FeedTest)
15.780 test_import_from_opml(FeedTest)
```

I'm sorry to say that `MiniTest` and the `test_benchmark` plugin are incompatible with each other, but I strongly encourage you to try `MiniTest`, since it'll make your tests faster, and will continue to be supported in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Recent versions of the `test-unit` gem also display time taken in verbose mode.

Comment: oops I've test this and I get: 
ARGH! someone defined Test::Unit::TestCase rather than requiring
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem test-unit (= 1.2.3) (Gem::LoadError)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run your unit tests under the ruby profiler by executing the code with `ruby -rprofile` instead of just `ruby`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm trying to run it like you said but i get this:

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/profiler.rb:13:in `hash': bignum too big to convert into `long' (RangeError)

Answer (score 0):

Minitest::Profile is a new gem that lists the top offenders after a standard test run.

https://github.com/nmeans/minitest-profile