# How long does each test take to run in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, timing

Is there a way to get a report of how long each test is taking to run on a Ruby on Rails project? I have a a small set of tests, 2 or 3, which take about 50% of the time and I'd like to find out which ones are.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722430/how-can-i-do-to-profile-ruby-unit-tests-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideas of the top of my mind:

1. test_benchmark: http://github.com/timocratic/test_benchmark
2. test_benchmarker: http://github.com/myronmarston/test_benchmarker/
3. If you are running rspec, you can use the command `--format profile` will give you the top 10 slowest tests
4. You could write data ... somewhere during setup and teardown of a test.